# font awesome without svg in angular 8

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I'm using a third party visual component I cannot change which uses icons everywere. It is expecting icons to behave like old font awesome, that is , a font + css classes.

I've npm installed angular-fontawesome but it seems to only use svg icons. 
It does not work anymore with , which the component renders:

```
<i class="fas fa-home">
```

Is there a way I can use it as just plain old css+webfont ?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved it by downloading FA locally,
extracted its webfonts and css files, 
threw all that into my assets folders, corrected paths in the css and works.
It's not the cleanest way to use this library, I know, but they seem to have sacrificed its simplicity in favour of some other features. This will do for me

Answer (score 0):

Have you come up with a better approach? I have a similar problem and was thinking about using a directive to convert this:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'file-contract']"></fa-icon>
```

To something like this, which is the output angular generates usually:

```
<fa-icon _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c455="" class="ng-fa-icon" ng-reflect-icon="fas,file-contract"><svg role="img" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="file-contract" class="svg-inline--fa fa-file-contract fa-w-12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M224 136V0H24C10.7 0 0 10.7 0 24v464c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h336c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V160H248c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24zM64 72c0-4.42 3.58-8 8-8h80c4.42 0 8 3.58 8 8v16c0 4.42-3.58 8-8 8H72c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8V72zm0 64c0-4.42 3.58-8 8-8h80c4.42 0 8 3.58 8 8v16c0 4.42-3.58 8-8 8H72c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8v-16zm192.81 248H304c8.84 0 16 7.16 16 16s-7.16 16-16 16h-47.19c-16.45 0-31.27-9.14-38.64-23.86-2.95-5.92-8.09-6.52-10.17-6.52s-7.22.59-10.02 6.19l-7.67 15.34a15.986 15.986 0 0 1-14.31 8.84c-.38 0-.75-.02-1.14-.05-6.45-.45-12-4.75-14.03-10.89L144 354.59l-10.61 31.88c-5.89 17.66-22.38 29.53-41 29.53H80c-8.84 0-16-7.16-16-16s7.16-16 16-16h12.39c4.83 0 9.11-3.08 10.64-7.66l18.19-54.64c3.3-9.81 12.44-16.41 22.78-16.41s19.48 6.59 22.77 16.41l13.88 41.64c19.77-16.19 54.05-9.7 66 14.16 2.02 4.06 5.96 6.5 10.16 6.5zM377 105L279.1 7c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H256v128h128v-6.1c0-6.3-2.5-12.4-7-16.9z"></path></svg></fa-icon>
```

I'm not sure that is the solution or if it would work. Does someone any suggestions?